# using dto Always getting a null value in a get request , many to one relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dto

this is my first time working with spring and Dto, and i was trying to create two enties, classes and student, my problem is when i try to send a get request of a classes , normaly the response need to be the name , numberS averageC and student related to this classe , but what i get is this {
"name": "phonexe",
"numberS": 25,
"averageC": 0.0,
"students": null
}
the students list is always null , i checked in the database if the student get inserted with the classe_id , so that's not the problem
this is my entities

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    private String codeM;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "classes_id")
    private Classes classes;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    private List<Notes> notes;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Classes {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;
    @NonNull
    @NotBlank(message = "First name must be filled")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^(?!\\s*$).+", message = "First name must not be blank or contain only spaces")
    private String name;
    @NonNull
    private Integer numberS;
    private double averageC=0.0;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Student> student;

}
```

and this is my Dto entities

```
@Data
public class StudentGetDto {
    @NotNull
    private String codeM;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private ClassesGetDto classes;
    private List<NotesGetWithMatiereOnlyDto> notes;
}
```

```
@Data
public class ClassesGetDto {
    private String name;
    private Integer numberS;
    private Double averageC;
    private List<StudentGetDto> students;
}
```

and this is the controller function

```
    @GetMapping("/{Name}")
    public ClassesGetDto findByName(@PathVariable String Name) throws Exception{
        return modelMapper.map(classesService.findByName(Name), ClassesGetDto.class);
    }
```

the modelMapper config

```
@Configuration
public class ModelMapperConfig {

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }
}
```

Comment: `modelMapper` might also be an issue. Can you please add the `modelMapper` class/config?

Comment: i added the modelMapper class

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that you're not having a lazy loading problem as mentioned before, you may check the Circular References: If there are circular references between your entities, it can cause issues during serialization to the DTO. Make sure there are no circular dependencies between the entities, as this can lead to infinite recursion or unexpected results. You can use annotations like @JsonIgnore or @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference to handle circular references properly during serialization.

Comment: ty adding @JsonIgnore to ignore any null value coming from the data base, it have always worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

`@OneToMany()` Default fetch type is Lazy.
Try using `FetchType.EAGER`.

Example:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Student> student;
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: modelMapper might also be an issue. Can you please add the `modelMapper` class/config?